# What is the convention for JavaScript test files?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cypress

I've seen a few files called `*.test.js`, `*-test.js`, `*.spec.js`, etc.

Is there an actual convention how to name JavaScript test files? Or is this dependent on the framework I use?

Comment: what exactly is a "test file"? you mean like for npm tests? not clear what what you're asking, but it sounds opinion based.

Comment: There's no convention.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After using several test frameworks, I feel the below is better:

For test file names, use as below:

1. `/test/*.test.js` - preferred, no need to explain.
2. `/test/*.spec.js` - OK, but new joinees always ask me - why?. A `spec` here means requirement specification.
3. `/test/*.test.txt` - preferred, if test cases are in a text file. A set of line(s) is a test case (see below).

For example:

- `a.js` is the main JavaScript file that should be tested
- `/test/a.test.js` is the test file that tests above `a.js`. Note that `/test/` is a test folder.

---

You may find `*.test.txt` new, so adding more details.

The format of one test case being three lines, can be in the below format in `*.test.txt`:

- `inputParam1 - may be the first parameter of a critical function which needs many tests`
- `inputParam2 - may be second parameter of a critical function which needs many tests`
- `expected`
- `inputParam1`
- `inputParam2`
- `expected`
- `...`

So, every three lines make one test case.

You may add the function name `line` like below, once in a while, which tests different function:

- `-func:someMethod1`
- `... (above input/expected lines)`
- `-func:someMethod2`
- `... (above input/expected lines)`

To execute a function name, or create a new object to a class, you can use `eval(className)`, `someMethod1[inputParam]`, etc. Though `eval` is not recommended, I use it as it is test framework which is not the production file. You will better ways than eval though if that is a concern.

After using several test frameworks, found this text file testing, by far most convenient for some special cases. (No need to format in JavaScript, JSON, etc.)

If you need, you may ignore that start with #, or //, or all blank lines.

So, I wrote my own framework that works this way.

- If you know a test framework that can read above format for `*.test.txt`, do comment below.
- Ping me if you need my code, will share via GitHub.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the framework, although most frameworks allow you to define a glob pattern to determine which files should be considered test files, e.g. the option [`testRegex`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testregex-string) in Jest. The default value for Jest will consider `*.test.js` and `*.js` files inside `__tests__` directories to be test files. In [Mocha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mocha_(JavaScript_framework)), it's the [`grep` option](https://mochajs.org/#-grep-regexp-g-regexp).

Answer (score -1):

I prefer *classServiceName.spec.ts*. Your question is tagged with unit testing, so I am assume you are testing a unit.

So if I have a component called *person.component.ts*, my test would be *person.component.spec.ts* and it would be in the same folder structure. If I had *person.service.ts* then the test would be *person.service.spec.ts* same folder structure.

You also had [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) in your tags, and so that is probably an integration test. I would name that to the page I am testing or the scenario. Sorry for assuming Angular and TypeScript.

Comment: same folder structure can also be achieved via .test.ts, I am not sure what's the benefit of this anwer? the preference did not seems adding actual benefit or justifiable reasoning... may want to revise the answer